# Why retryWhen operator does not resubscribe to the flow again?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Look, i created the issue on StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nndpag

I can't figure out how to use `retryWhen` operator properly. 
I expect it to resubscribe to my promise `from(getPromise())` and cycle it until it emits desired value. I definitely need to use `retryWhen` operator as I can set delay logic.

At this moment it gets stuck in `retryWhen` operator if the promise generates wrong number first time (see example on StackBlitz).

It seems it is related as I use promise instead of observable input but I doubt that is. 
So, Rxjs community, I count on your notes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the source (promise object) was created once instead of creating it every time as an error throws. So I got to use empty source as initial source:

```
const source = empty()
  .pipe(
    defaultIfEmpty(undefined)
  )
```

And then I can switch to **new promise** object with `switchMap` operator:

```
const source = empty()
  .pipe(
    defaultIfEmpty(undefined),
    switchMap(v => getPromise())
  )
```

So the next resubscriptions will be given new promises.
Here is the correct StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yrxace
Now it works as I expect - It continues until it gets right number.

Comment: `defer(() => getPromise())` is the way to go, IMO: https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875